# Running origen-sdk commands in Bamboo

Tags: origen-sdk

Has anyone run Origen application commands in Bamboo?  Something along the lines of:

1. `git clone myapp.git`
2. `cd myapp`
3. `bundle install`
4. `origen p myflow.rb`

I see that the lbin directory (where bundle lives) is ignored in the .gitignore yet shows up in the application.  Having issues running the `bundle install`, saying it cannot find `bundle`.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Origen needs to get first crack at running Bundler within a new workspace so that it can provide a default configuration, so the flow should be:

1. `git clone myapp.git`
2. `cd myapp`
3. `origen -v`   # Just a throwaway invocation, lbin should be created by this
4. `origen p myflow.rb`

However, sometimes it can be hard to add `./lbin` to the path in the Bamboo/CI environment like you can in your personal env, so quite often we run in CI like this:

1. `git clone myapp.git`
2. `cd myapp`
3. `bundle install`
4. `bundle exec origen p myflow.rb`

That's a more conventional/direct way of running with Bundler, but who wants to type `bundle exec` everytime, so it is better in a user env to just let Origen configure Bundler for you to use its binstubs feature.

If you can't run `bundle`, then it probably means that Bundler is not installed to your base Ruby installation in this environment.
You should have both Bundler and Origen installed to the base Ruby in order to be able to boot Origen applications.

Comment: what is the binstubs feature?  Also, do you keep the lbin directory in Git?

Comment: I don't check in lbin, and by default it is in gitignore. The reason being is that it is platform/environment specific.
If you always run in the same env, you probably can check it in and it will work fine. You might run into problems going from Linux to Windows though, for example.
For binstubs - https://bundler.io/v1.16/man/bundle-binstubs.1.html